# Altium designer - Messages panel doesn't show up

Tags: pcb, altium

When I compile my project the Messages panel does not appear. Even if I manually try to open it through System -> Messages (bottom right corner) or View -> Workspace Panels -> System -> Messages it doesn't work. I've also tried to close and reopen the project, loading old projects, etc. but none of this has worked. It must be some kind of bug.

Is there any way to solve this or at least to see the errors without this panel?

Comment: The messages from compile is set (default) to only open on errors. How to open it depends on the version you are running. It may also not open manually if not set to open always.

Comment: @Peter Smith When I transfer the design from the schematic to the PCB a warning says: "Errors occurred during compilation of the project" and next to this message a place to "click" to see this errors that naturally doesn't work either. So my project do have errors for sure. How can i set if i want it to open the panel alwys or not?

Comment: Which Altium Version is used? On some PC I have seen that the message pannel was opened but located on the  Display where it was located last time. Unfortunately the display was now not connected anymore which caused that the panel was not displayed at all. Try to disconnect & re-connect one Display after the other.